# problema al enviar datos con ajax

Tags: php, ajax, web

Hola buen día estoy practicando ajax pero estoy teniendo un problema y no se cual es ayudenme porfavor.

El cuerpo de la página llamada index.html es la sgte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
        <input type="text" id="nombre">
        <input type="text" id="apellido">
        <input type="submit" value="Validar" onclick="ajax();">
        <div id="info"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ajax(){

            var resultado = document.getElementById("info");
            var xmlhttp;

            if(windows.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            var a = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
            var b = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
            var infoDato = "nombre="+a+"&apellido="+b;

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
                        var mensaje = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        resultado.innerHTML = mensaje;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("POST","servidor.php",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","applicaction/x-www- 
            form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send(infoDato);
           }
       </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

El cual manda los datos a servidor.php

```
<?php

   $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
   $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];

  if(empty($nombre) || empty($apellido)){
    echo "Ingrese nombre y apellido";
  }else{
    echo "Hola ".$nombre." ".$apellido;
 }

 ?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es solamente la validación de las cajas de texto que se ingrese un nombre y apellido. Pero no aparece mensaje en el div

Comment: ¿En `responsseText` no sobra una s?

Comment: Ya lo arregle pero igual no me aparece el mensaje

Comment: Me parece que `resultado` no esta disponible dentro de la función `onreadystatechange`. Prueba a hacer el `document.getElementById("info")` dentro de la funcion.

Comment: Eso también lo había intentado pero sigue sin aparecer el mensaje. Me pregunto si xampp tendrá algo que ver?

Comment: No debería afectarle. Haz la llamada a servidor.php desde el navegador a ver si te da el mensaje "Ingrese nombre y apellido";

Comment: Si, aparecen Undefined y el mensaje "Ingrese nombre y apellido".

Comment: if(windows.XMLHttpRequest) es "window" no "windows"

Comment: Yo diría que tienes mal la ruta de servidor.php y que no te está llegando a ese archivo desde la llamada ajax

Comment: Corregí el error de "windows" a "window" pero cuando ingreso datos o no ingreso nada presiono el botón y solo aparece el mensaje  "Ingrese nombre y apellido" junto con los mensajes de Undefined; la ruta creo que esta bien como `servidor.php` nada más ya que ambos archivos están en la misma carpeta.

Comment: Gracias a todos por responder al parecer los problemas estaban en `windows` el cual era `window` y en la parte del `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader` estaba como applicaction y es `application` . Disculpen por haberlos molestado con estos simples problemas y nuevamente gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score -2):

Cambia tu código por este:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">
        <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido">
        <input type="button" value="Validar" onclick="ajaxS();">
        <div id="info"></div>

<script>
    function ajaxS(){
            var a = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
            var b = document.getElementById("apellido").value;

            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = 'servidor.php';
            var params = "nombre="+a+"&apellido="+b;
            http.open('POST', url, true);

            //Send the proper header information along with the request
            http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
                if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                        var mensaje = http.responseText;
                        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = mensaje;
                }
            }
            http.send(params);          
             }
 </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```